# Node.JS migration to 18.14.1 version issue: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I have migrated from node.js `16.15.0` to `18.14.1`.

Right now, I am having an error coming from `babel-loader.js` in a custom framework (just FYI for the `react` based advice) :

[image]

This is what I am having in the place where issue is coming:

```
var filename = function filename(source, identifier, options) {
  var hash = crypto.createHash("md4");
  var contents = JSON.stringify({
    source: source,
    options: options,
    identifier: identifier
  });

  hash.update(contents);

  return hash.digest("hex") + ".json.gz";
 };
```

As I understand, the origin of the issue comes from Webpack using the MD4 algorithm in its build process, which is no longer supported in the latest Node.js version. So I have updated the webpack version to `5.75.0` (doesn't help at all) and also I decided to patch the `babel-loader` dependency, by switching the algorithm from `md4` to `md5`:

```
var filename = function filename(source, identifier, options) {
  var hash;
  try {
    hash = crypto.createHash("md4");
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn('Crypto "md4" is not supported anymore by this Node version');
    hash = crypto.createHash("md5");
  }
  var contents = JSON.stringify({
    source: source,
    options: options,
    identifier: identifier
  });

  hash.update(contents);

  return hash.digest("hex") + ".json.gz";
};
```

I am not having this error anymore, BUT the content is not being rendered and I am having a lot of issues in the console. I believe it's because I changed the way of hashing, but I also have to do the proper un-hashing in `babel-loader.js`. Will be super grateful for any advices on it

p.s.: please don't advise to downgrade the node.js version